# ¿Cómo puedo alinear items en un toolbar? Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un menu con 3 items dentro de un toolbar y quiero poner un item a la izquierda, otro en el centro y otro a la derecha. Por defecto salen los 3 a la derecha, de esta manera:

[image: Items alineados a la derecha]

Este es mi toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/azulClaro"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
android:id="@+id/toolBar">
```

Este es el menu con sus 3 items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_profile"
    android:title="Perfil"
    android:icon="@mipmap/profile_dark"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


<item
    android:id="@+id/action_messages"
    android:title="Mensajes"
    android:icon="@mipmap/messages"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_filter"
    android:title="Filtro"
    android:icon="@mipmap/filter"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

He intentado editar desde styles.xml pero no hay manera.

Comment: el menu siempre va a salir a la derecha, debes crearte un toolbar personalizado

Comment: Mi toolbar es personalizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer un `layout` para cada item del menu, donde colocas el ícono
y "juegas" con los `padding` (Left, Right) para alinearlos: 
custom_menu_profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@mipmap/profile_dark"
android:paddingRight="30dp" />
```

Agregas ese layout al item menu:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_profile"
android:title="Perfil"
app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_menu_profile"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

En este caso la función del onClick ya no va ir en `onOptionsItemSelected`
sino en `onCreateOptionsMenu` de esta forma:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.tu_menu, menu);
final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_profile);
item.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(TuActivity.this, "PROFILE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 });
return true;
```

Además en el `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` puedes agregar estas propiedades:

```
android:paddingEnd="30dp"
android:paddingStart="30dp"
```

Comment: Con esto lo he podido hacer sin problemas. Muchas gracias por la respuesta y correcta solución!

Apunte: Al poner el paddingEnd y paddingStart, android me requiere poner lo siguiente:

android:paddingRight="60dp"
    android:paddingLeft="60dp">

Comment: Una pregunta, como puedo referenciar ahora a cada item?